# android autostart application

Tags: android

I want my app to be start automatically when my device is boot up. I have implemented the service. Now the problem is whenever my device is connected to the PC through data cable app does not crash. But when device is not connected to PC app gets crashed. I m not able it trace the log cat as well for this because device is not connected.

Pls advice me somethg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an app called "Log Collector", it contains Stacktraces and you can use it to view or send the systemlog to an email-address:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector

Answer (score 0):

You can get logcat data collected while device is disconnected. Use `adb logcat` from SDK to dump collected logs.